# How can I use custom web fonts in django cms icons

Tags: python-3.x, django, content-management-system, font-awesome, django-cms

My question is how does the `/admin/djangocms_icon/includes/assets.html` file look like? Can someone give a sample supposing I am using font awesome 5? Below are the configuration settings that I followed on Github.

### Configuration

This addon provides a `default` template for all instances. You can provide
additional template choices by adding a `DJANGOCMS_ICON_TEMPLATES`

setting::

```
DJANGOCMS_ICON_TEMPLATES = [
    ('svg', 'SVG template'),
]
```

Web Font Icons
##############

The django CMS Icon plugin ships with **Font Awesome 4 as default**. This can
be changed by overriding the following setting::

```
DJANGOCMS_ICON_SETS = [
    ('fontawesome4', 'fa', 'Font Awesome 4'),
]
```

To use Font Awesome 5 in the above example; see the options below from the `DJANGOCMS_ICON_SETS`listed.

In addition **you need to load** the resources for your fonts in `/admin/djangocms_icon/includes/assets.html`. Add this file to your project
in order for the icon picker to pick up your custom icons in the admin.

The icon picker supports `numerous font libraries <http://victor-valencia.github.io/bootstrap-iconpicker/>`
out of the box. You can also add multiple font sets like this::

```
DJANGOCMS_ICON_SETS = [
    ('elusiveicon', 'el', 'Elusive Icons'),
    ('flagicon', 'flag-icon', 'Flag Icons'),
    ('fontawesome4', 'fa', 'Font Awesome 4'),
    ('fontawesome5regular', 'far', 'Font Awesome 5 Regular'),
    ('fontawesome5solid', 'fas', 'Font Awesome 5 Solid'),
    ('fontawesome5brands', 'fab', 'Font Awesome 5 Brands'),
    ('fontawesome5light', 'fal', 'Font Awesome 5 Light', 
    '5.3.1_pro'),
    ('glyphicon', 'glyphicon', 'Glyphicons'),
    ('ionicon', 'ion', 'Ionicons Icons'),
    ('mapicon', 'map-icon', 'Map Icons'),
    ('materialdesign', 'zmdi', 'Material Design'),
    ('octicon', 'octicon', 'Octicons'),
    ('typicon', 'typcn', 'Typicons'),
    ('weathericon', 'wi', 'Weather Icons'),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to figure this out myself. It depends on whether you're trying to include a preconfigured font or your own.

#### Including preconfigured fonts

There is an example of an `assets.html` provided in [the official repository](https://github.com/django-cms/djangocms-icon/blob/master/djangocms_icon/templates/admin/djangocms_icon/includes/assets.html) at `djangocms_icon/templates/admin/djangocms_icon/includes/assets.html` and it's in fact linking to Font Awesome 5 (5.3.1 specifically):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

In order to include another font:

- Copy the `assets.html` file into your `templates` folder at `templates/admin/djangocms_icon/includes/assets.html` (it overrides the template's default),
- Add another `<link>` referring to your (external or local) font(s) of choice,
- Add the references in your `settings.py`'s `DJANGOCMS_ICON_SETS` by copying the respective element(s) from the docs.

#### Including custom fonts

For custom fonts, it's a tad more complicated. In my case, I only had a single `.ttf` file with custom icons, no CSS. In this case, the `assets.html` looks like this:

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/icons/my_icons.css' %}">
```

In `my_icons.css`, include the font with an `@font-face`-rule and add a general `myicon` class plus individual classes for each of the icons:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "My Icons";
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

    src: url("../../fonts/MyIcons.ttf") format("truetype");
}

.myicon {
  font-family:"My Icons";
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: inherit;
}

.myicon-A:before {
  content:"A";
}
.myicon-B:before {
  content:"B";
}
.myicon-C:before {
  content:"C";
}

...
```

Next, put a JSON file at `static/js/my_icons.js` (or wherever you want) with a list of all the icon classes:

```
{
  "iconClass": "myicon",
  "icons": ["myicon-A",
            "myicon-B",
            "myicon-C",
            "myicon-D",
            ...
            ]
}
```

(To generate all possible symbols, I opened the font in MacOS's font manager, copied all of the glyphs with cmd-A/cmd-C - they are really just letters - and used that to generate the rules with a short Python script.)

Finally, in your `settings.py`, you load the JSON and set up the reference to your custom font:

```
with open('path/to/static/js/my_icons.js')) as iconfile:
    MY_ICON_SET = iconfile.read()


DJANGOCMS_ICON_SETS = [
    (MY_ICON_SET, # = the content of the JSON file
     'myicon',    # = the css class
     'My Icons'   # = the label in the admin interface
     ),
]
```

That should be it. Don't forget to include your custom font in your website as well (e.g. in the header of your `base.html` template) for the icons to show up in the content as well.